# How to import Xodus in Java?

Tags: java, xodus

I have added the dependency to my `pom.xml`:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jetbrains.xodus</groupId>
        <artifactId>xodus-openAPI</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.124</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jetbrains.xodus</groupId>
        <artifactId>xodus-environment</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.124</version>
    </dependency>
```

But it's the only one that doesn't seem to work when I import it in a Java class. I tried many different ways to import it, such as `import org.jetbrains.exodus.env.Environments;` but none of them work.

I am using JDK 11 and Netbeans 11.2.

Comment: try reimporting the maven dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right package for Environments API is `jetbrains.exodus.env`, so `import jetbrains.exodus.env.Environments;`should work.